# how to generate random number with find and sed?

Tags: bash

how to generate random number in this code?
I try use $RANDOM, but the number is still the same. How to improve it?

```
find . -type f  -exec sed -i 's/<field name=\"test/<field name=\"test$RANDOM/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Please, avoid parsing HTML/XML with regular expressions.

Comment: can you explain me, why?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a brief list of reasons.

Comment: thx, but I need this solution for my 30 projects and it was the fastest way. It was a one situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the `$RANDOM` function invocation is substituted with its result when you run the `find` command, not when `find` runs the `sed` command.

What you can do is put the `sed -i ...` part in a script, and pass this script to `find` instead.

For instance, if `subst.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
r=$RANDOM
sed -i "s/<field name=\"test/<field name=\"test${r}/g" $@
```

Then

```
find . -type f -exec ./subst.sh {} \;
```

should do the trick, because `$RANDOM` is going to be evaluated as many times as there are files.

(Note that the random number will still be the same across one particular file, but it will be distinct for different files.)

Comment: It works! Thanks! Sorry, I'm new in bash, what does it mean $@ ?

Comment: It's the array of all command-line arguments to the script. In this case, passing the first argument would have sufficed, so you could also have written $1.

Answer (score 2):

you can also avoid creating a script file with this "one line" way, ex.:

```
function FUNCtst() { echo "tst:$1";echo "tst2:$1"; }; export -f FUNCtst; find -exec bash -c 'FUNCtst {}' \;
```

so, you:

1. create a complex function
2. export -f the funcion
3. find executing bash, that calls the exported funcion

and, no need to create a file!