# Appending unique IDs to existing strings

Tags: regex, bash, sed, uniqueidentifier

I have the following file:

```
blue yellow red black yellow
blue red black yellow red black
yellow red red purple yellow
```

How do I append a unique ID to each occurrence of the word `red` so that the output is similar to this:

```
blue yellow red1376049638182 black yellow
blue red13760496381928 black yellow red1376049631827 black
yellow red1376049631988 red13760496371827 purple yellow
```

I tried the following command:

```
sed "s/red/red$(node -e 'console.log(new Date().getTime())'; sleep 0.001s)/g" file
```

but very soon realized that the ID (in this case a time) is only generated once and replaced globally in the entire file. Thus, the solution must somehow use a loop though I'm not sure how to filter out the occurrences of red and make sure each has a unique ID appended to it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835407/how-to-generate-random-number-with-find-and-sed

Comment: @fedorqui that works then you're replacing one time in multiple files (i.e. using `find`) but I want to search a single file with multiple occurrences of the same string. Simply said, what is the equivalent of `find` that searches through a file sequentially so that I can stop at every hit and fire off a replace?

Comment: @fedorqui The related one would replace the *same* random string everywhere in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to create a random number.  I'm not a big fan of `$RANDOM` so I'd create one using `/dev/urandom`.  If you want 16-digit random number, you can say:

```
function myrandom() {
  cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:digit:]' | fold -w 16 | head -1
}
```

Now use sed to replace the desired string with the *function* and `eval` it later.  Note that I've advised `sed` to take care of word boundaries while replacing the string:

```
sed 's/\bred\b/red$(myrandom)/g' inputfile | while read -r line; do eval echo "${line}"; done
```

A sample invocation on your given input would result in:

```
blue yellow red5004720098524945 black yellow
blue red7014391283176465 black yellow red9350810549791982 black
yellow red4276472966991005 red6986710362535116 purple yellow
```

Comment: This is great, very elegant!! I wish I knew about `eval` before! Thank you!

Comment: One more question about this approach. What if the line contains some special characters such as `;` or `>`. Is these any way ignore these and tell `eval` to only execute subshell commands?

Comment: Not really. An alternative would be to use your original approach with one substitution per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
#!/bin/bash

IN=in.txt
OUT=out.txt
KEY="red"

rm -f $OUT

while read LINE
do
  QLINE=
  NEWQLINE=" $LINE "
  echo $QLINE : $NEWQLINE
  while [ "$NEWQLINE" != "$QLINE" ]
  do
    QLINE="$NEWQLINE"
    ID=$(uuidgen)
    ID=${ID//-/}
    NEWQLINE="${QLINE/ $KEY / $KEY$ID }"
  done
  echo "${QLINE:1:-1}" >> $OUT
done < $IN
```